# Python error "version OPENSSL_1.0.0 not defined in file libcrypto.so.1.0.0..." when trying to run command in PHP scrip (LAMPP)

Tags: python, php, lamp, openssl

When in Ubuntu 14.04:

- I run a command of script written in `Python` with shell **it normally runs**.
- I try to run same command using `PHP` (`lampp`) I get this error:

```
    [errors] => Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  .
  .
  .
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 61, in 
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.i386-linux-gnu.so: symbol GENERAL_NAME_free, version OPENSSL_1.0.0 not defined in file libcrypto.so.1.0.0 with link time reference
```

How to fix it and let the script finish?

Some notes:

- I have installed latest openssl which I tried to reinstall
- I tried to reinstall Python2.7 too

**Update:**

I tried to install normal server on my local machine. By "normal server" I mean `apache2`, `php5`, `mysql`, `phpmyadmin`. And it works.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install normal server on my local machine. By "normal server" I mean `apache2`, `php5`, `mysql`, `phpmyadmin`. And it works. `Lampp` was removed.